# Plugin makes options dropdown not working in opencart product

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

I have a problem with `Option` tab on Add/Edit product. The problem is that when I installed the extension `Autocomplete No More` and when I choose Option it throws this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getOptionData() on null in /../ocartdata/storage/modification/admin/controller/catalog/option.php:437
```

in `option.php` line 437 is

```
$option_data = $this->model_extension_catalog_autocomplete_no_more->getOptionData($this->request->post['option_id']);
```

And full function is this one

```
public function getOptionData() {
    
    if (isset($this->request->post['option_id'])) {

        $this->load->language('catalog/option');            
        $this->load->model('catalog/autocomplete_no_more');         
        $this->load->model('tool/image');
        
        $option_data = $this->model_extension_catalog_autocomplete_no_more->getOptionData($this->request->post['option_id']);
                        
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($option_data));
    }
}
```

Is anyone has an idea why this throws null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue:

You are trying to call a method of an Object

```php
$this->model_extension_catalog_autocomplete_no_more
```

with the ***extension*** in the object name.

but then you are loading the model without the **extension** in the path:

```php
$this->load->model('catalog/autocomplete_no_more')
```

So obviously the Error signals that you have not yet defined this object

`Call to a member function getOptionData() on null`

### Solution:

Fix it by adding extension to the path:

```php
$this->load->model('extension/catalog/autocomplete_no_more')
```

or remove if from the object name:

```php
$this->model_catalog_autocomplete_no_more
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This `$this->model_catalog_autocomplete_no_more` works perfectly!

Comment: glad It helped!